# Period (or %2E) at the end of a url parameter results in page not found error

Tags: iis, iis-6, rewrite

I'm using IIS6 with URL rewriting to create search engine friendly URLs for a website that I've been working on.  I'm having a bit of trouble when error messages are passed back as URL parameters.

Page cannot be found:

- http://orderDetails/orderId/1/reason/order%20status%20updated%2E

These work fine:

- http://orderDetails/orderId/1/reason/order%20status%20updated
- http://orderDetails/orderId/1/reason/order%20status%20updated%2Ehjh

I believe that the period at the end of the message is being interpreted as a file extension delimiter.  Someone suggested that the period might mess up the URL rewriting but I've checked the log and the URL rewriting appears to be working.

Comment: im having this problem too....